# What happens if I do not encode the lables or classifiers in the data?

Tags: decision-trees, encoding, classifier

I have a data where the three variables are numerical and one variable is a string. I am using the simple decision tree algorithm. Read somewhere that the data in strings must be encoded with one hot encoding. Will this affect the accuracy of my system ?